# Load Eloquent Model Relationships Child Nodes in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I can't return $parent->child() | I get null;

Parent Model

```
class PrinterSetting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'printer_settings';
    //fillables here
    protected $with = ['copies'];

    public function copies(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\DB\PrinterCopy\PrinterCopy::class, 'printer_id');
    }

}
```

Child Model

```
class PrinterCopy extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'printer_copies';

    public function printer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\DB\PrinterSetting\PrinterSetting::class, 'id', 'printer_id');
    }

}
```

Code in Controller:

```
$availablePrinters = $this->printerSetting->where('is_active', 1)->get();
foreach($availablePrinters as $availablePrinter)
{
   //working
   foreach($availablePrinter->copies() as $copy)
   {
   //Not working
   }
}
```

I can't find the reason why it's not working.
I Tried to dump $availablePrinter->copies and it work, but ofcourse I can't insert it on foreach() loop.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$availablePrinter->copies()` return Query builder, you have to use `$availablePrinter->copies` which is Collection that you can add in loop, Try this

```
$availablePrinters = $this->printerSetting->where('is_active', 1)->get();

foreach($availablePrinters as $availablePrinter)
{
   //working
   foreach($availablePrinter->copies as $copy)
   {
       dd($copy)
   }
}
```

Side note, also fix your `belongsTo` relation in `PrinterCopy` model, it should be like this

```
public function printer(){
   return $this->belongsTo(\App\DB\PrinterSetting\PrinterSetting::class,'printer_id');
}
```

Comment: thanks, you're right. what I did is I store first $availablePrinter->copies into a variable, and I used foreach($variable as $key => value){} syntax. and it worked. thanks..